# How to assign the color by putting the actual color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've saw an example (please see the attached image) of the color being added by a sort of emoji style.

Where can I find the color list and add it to the code directly?

[image]

Comment: `let color = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it easily by writing: `Color Literal`.

I can also add that you can type `Image literal` for images.

Comment: Yeah. There's a lot of cool features. Hope you liked the answer! @SLN

Answer (score 1):

Starting typing it out as `Color Literal`, then select that as autocomplete suggestion and you'll be presented with color options.

```
navigateButton.backgroundColor = Color L... // select Color Literal in auto-complete
```